# Unix command output to HTML file

Tags: html, unix, mutt

I am building a log file and sending it as mutt in html format.

I am using copy command in verbose mode to output to HTML file format.

```
cp -v files name
```

output inside html file

```
'filename' -> 'filename'
```

I believe the `'` is causing my html file to be corrupted.
I am using following command,

`cp -v -R ${UNIX_PACKAGES_DIR}/Unix/* ${TARGET_DIR} | tee -a {EXEC_LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted. It doesn't help if you just downvote without giving any clear description.

Answer (score 0):

The '>' symbol is used for output (STDOUT) redirection.

ls -al > listings

have you tried using pipes? |

Comment: I am not asking how to output. I am saying because cp verbose mode prints ' , it is corrupting my html file. I have no issues with output to html file.